# Is it possible to kickstart a 16.04.3 install?

Tags: 16.04, kickstart

We have an existing kickstart server.  It was originally built to build 16.04.0.  but over the years, the installed machine kept going up in updates. 16.04.1, then .2  the last machine it kickstarted was 16.04.6.  What I klike to know is it possible to kickstart a particular update 16.04.3 for example.  somehow our clients is afraid the update would break their application.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to us, here are what I did:
1. go to old-releases.ubuntu.com, traverse down to the exact release, download the ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso to kickstart server.
2. Move the iso to any place under apache's DocumentRoot (i.e. /var/www/html), then create a subdirectory, i.e. /var/www/html/u16.04.3 , then run 'mount -o loop,ro /var/www/html/ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso /var/www/html/u16.04.3' 
3. change the url line in the ks.cfg file to 'url --url=http://kickstart-server/u16.04.3/ubuntu'
These are what I did in my environment, just throw out the ideas, hope this help.